# rref($R^TR$)=R, R is a reduced matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Textbook Equation]

Why does this hold? For example, if we had $I$ be 2 x 2 and then took F to be the matrix [0 1]
[2 0], then $R^TR$ row reduced doesn't equal $R$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.